# Does ViewModelViewHost work at design time for WPF? (ReactiveUI)

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I cannot get a `ViewModelViewHost` to work at design time in Visual Studio. Is this by design or have I set something up wrong?

In my view's ctor I have:

```
  Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeSplat();
  Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeReactiveUI();
  Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new SessionView(), typeof(IViewFor<SessionViewModel>));
```

In my view's XAML I have:

```
<d:DesignProperties.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel.ChildViewModel>
            <local:SessionViewModel/>
        </local:MainWindowViewModel.ChildViewModel>
    </local:MainWindowViewModel>
</d:DesignProperties.DataContext>

<reactiveUi:ViewModelViewHost ViewModel="{Binding ChildViewModel}"/>
```

`SessionView` is an `IViewFor<SessionViewModel>`.

There is a comment [here](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/b418df64918da0c78a378af1b846afbab0f4e5ae/src/ReactiveUI/Xaml/ViewModelViewHost.cs#L69) in the `ViewModelViewHost` ctor indicating that in design mode it will return before trying to create a view. But it seems strange that `InUnitTestRunner` should return true if there is a seperate `InDesignMode` property for that purpose.

```
  // NB: InUnitTestRunner also returns true in Design Mode
  if (ModeDetector.InUnitTestRunner()) {
     ViewContractObservable = Observable.Never<string>();
     return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a late reply our apologies.

The answer is this is deliberate.

We have stuff that will break the XAML designer if ReactiveUI's code is allowed to initialize in the constructor. Hence why we don't run the values.